# Grid Engine - How to detect cluster node status?

Tags: scheduler, altair, sungridengine

I'm currently working with `Altair Grid Engine` and I need to find a way to determine the status of each node in `Altair Grid Engine` (i.e., whether it is running or stopped). I have already tried a couple of commands, but they don't provide the information I need.

Here's what I have attempted so far:

`qconf -sel`: This command helped me obtain a list of registered nodes in the cluster. However, it doesn't provide any specific information about the state or status of each node.

`qconf -se <cluster-node-name>`: This command gives me cluster information for a specific node. Unfortunately, the information returned doesn't include any details about the node's state or status.

I tried with `qhost -F`, it does show the cluster information but, not the current status of that node.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to detect the status of each cluster node accurately. Is there any other command or method that I should try?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qstat -u -f <queue_name>
```

The `-f` option causes summary information on all queues to be displayed along with the queued job list.

Example:

```
qstat -f -q 12cores.q

queuename        qtype resv/used/tot. load_avg arch          states
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12cores.q@node01.local   BIP   0/0/12         -NA-     lx-amd64     au
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12cores.q@node02.local   BIP   0/12/12        12.00    lx-amd64      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12cores.q@node03.local   BIP   0/12/12        11.97    lx-amd64      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12cores.q@node04.local   BIP   0/12/12        12.02    lx-amd64      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12cores.q@node05.local   BIP   0/12/12        12.03    lx-amd64      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by the status of a node.  In gridengine the status shows up on the queue instances.  You could try either **qhost -q**
or use **qselect -qs u** ;**qselect -qs E** ;**qselect -qs a** to get a list
of queue instances on uncontactable hosts, queue instances in an error state or alarmed queue instances.